# Equal margins in twosided report?

Tags: geometry, double-sided, report

**Background.** I have written a document with the `report` document class, where I've been using the `twoside` option for printing purposes (and other nice things that come with that option, such as `openright`, and the possibility to distinguish between even and odd pages when working with `fancyhdr`).

A (sort of) minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{report} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\chapter{First chapter}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

**Problem.** I now want to create an online version of the report, identical to the printed version in all aspects except that the left and right margin should be 'evened out' (i.e. set to their average), to make it look better on a computer screen.

Changing to `oneside` instead of `twoside` doesn't seem to work without causing problems with `openright` and `fancyhdr`. I have also tried `\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}` but that causes unwanted changes to other geometric parameters such as the textwidth.

Any ideas about what can be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the terminal I do

```
> latexdef -v -c [a4paper,twoside,11pt]report textheight textwidth

\the\textheight:
595.80026pt


\the\textwidth:
360.0pt
```

The “mysterious” value for the height is for accomodating 44 lines (43 times the 13.6pt baselineskip plus the 11pt topskip).

Add the information to the parameters to `geometry` (and don't forget to set the head height in any case):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,textwidth=360pt,textheight=595.8pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
  \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\chapter{First chapter}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Just for checking: in the log file I get

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* hratio: 1:1
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(118.75394pt, 360.0pt, 118.75394pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(99.69861pt, 595.80026pt, 149.54797pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=360.0pt
* \textheight=595.80026pt
* \oddsidemargin=46.48395pt
* \evensidemargin=46.48395pt
* \topmargin=-9.57138pt
* \headheight=13.6pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=103.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

If the call to `geometry` is changed to

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

we get

```
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* pass: disregarded the geometry package!
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=360.0pt
* \textheight=595.80026pt
* \oddsidemargin=22.0pt
* \evensidemargin=70.0pt
* \topmargin=18.0pt
* \headheight=13.6pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=103.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)
```

and you can check that the relevant parameters are exactly the same.

Do you need `latexdef` and the terminal? No: just add

```
text width: \the\textwidth

text height: \the\textheight
```

after `\begin{document}` and look up the values in the PDF file.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. There is one difference left: The `\topmargin` set by `geometry` is smaller than in the original sample. Do you have an idea on how to fix this?